# How can I store a DateTime + TimeZoneInfo.Id in a way Entity Framework likes?

Tags: entity-framework, datetime, entity-framework-core, timezone

I need to store appointment start/end times in the underlying database. So that means storing for each time a DateTime + TimeZoneInfo.Id for each. I have the class I created below. But I have a couple of questions around this:

1. Can this be placed in an EF model class as a struct? I've tried that and can't get it to work. So at present I'm declaring it a class and placing it in the table using `builder.OwnsOne(e => e.StartDateTime)`
2. Should I have a 3rd column in the class with the DateTimeUTC where I run a daemon every Sunday night that updates that to match the local DateTime + TimeZoneId? I can set DateTimeUTC every time I create/update a record. So the daemon only needs to look at future appointments where timezone changes may have caused an issue. Or is this over-engineering?
3. When a user wants to see events for the next week, do I need to go to the UTC DateTime? Or can I use the local DateTime since to them, that is the times they view as the next week?
4. Is there a way I can tell EF how to do a comparison between a value and this object? I can do `Start.DateTime < var.DateTime` but I'd like to be able to do `Start < var'
5. Is there anything I've missed in approaching it this way?

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// A combined date and time with a time zone offset. The DateTime whenever passed in, if not set to Unspecified,
   /// is silently converted to Unspecified, not changing the DateTime value.
   /// </summary>
   public class DateTimeZone : IComparable<DateTimeZone>
   {
        private DateTime _dateTime;

        /// <summary>
        /// The DateTime. This will always return DateTimeKind.Unspecified. The setter will silently convert
        /// to DateTimeKind.Unspecified if needed, <b>not</b> changing the DateTime if it does so.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime DateTime
        {
            get => _dateTime;
            private set => _dateTime = value.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified ? value : DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The TimeZoneId. These are defined in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.id
        /// </summary>
        public string TimeZoneId { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The TimeZoneInfo for the TimeZoneId. This is created on the fly and is not stored in the database as its
        /// underlying data can change when timezone rules are changed.
        /// </summary>
        [NotMapped]
        public TimeZoneInfo TimeZoneInfo => TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZoneId);

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the DateTime field converted to UTC.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime ConvertToUtc
        {
            get
            {
                Trap.Break();
                return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new DateTimeZone with the current time and the passed in TimeZoneId.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dateTime">The DateTime. DateTimeKind will be silently set to Unspecified.</param>
        /// <param name="timeZoneId">The TimeZone Id.</param>
        public DateTimeZone(DateTime dateTime, string timeZoneId)
        {
            if (dateTime.Kind != DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
                dateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

            DateTime = dateTime;
            TimeZoneId = timeZoneId;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create the object with the current time and the local timezone.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTimeZone()
        {
            DateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
            TimeZoneId = TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create and return a new object that is converted to the passed in TimeZoneId. This <b>will</b> adjust
        /// the DateTime property by the difference in the time zones.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="timeZoneId">Adjust the returned datetime to the matching time in this timezone.</param>
        /// <returns>The DateTime in the requested timezone.</returns>
        public DateTimeZone ConvertTimeZone(string timeZoneId)
        {
            if (timeZoneId == TimeZoneId)
                return this;

            Trap.Break();
            var destTimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId);
            var dateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime, TimeZoneInfo, destTimeZoneInfo);

            return new DateTimeZone(dateTime, timeZoneId);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns with the DateTime set to Now in the passed in TimeZoneId.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="timeZoneId">Return Now in this timezone.</param>
        /// <returns>DateTime.Now in the requested timezone.</returns>
        public static DateTimeZone Now(string timeZoneId)
        {
            var now = new DateTimeZone(DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id);
            return now.ConvertTimeZone(timeZoneId);
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public int CompareTo(DateTimeZone? other)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) 
                return 0;

            if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) 
                return 1;

            // if they have the same timezone, compare the dates
            if (TimeZoneId == other.TimeZoneId)
                return _dateTime.CompareTo(other._dateTime);

            // ok, convert both to UTC and then compare the dates.
            Trap.Break();
            var utc1 = ConvertTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.Utc.Id);
            var utc2 = other.ConvertTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.Utc.Id);

            return utc1.CompareTo(utc2);
        }

        public static bool operator <(DateTimeZone x, DateTimeZone y) => x.CompareTo(y) < 0;
        public static bool operator <=(DateTimeZone x, DateTimeZone y) => x.CompareTo(y) <= 0;
        public static bool operator >(DateTimeZone x, DateTimeZone y) => x.CompareTo(y) > 0;
        public static bool operator >=(DateTimeZone x, DateTimeZone y) => x.CompareTo(y) >= 0;

        public static bool operator !=(DateTimeZone x, DateTimeZone y) => x.CompareTo(y) != 0;
        public static bool operator ==(DateTimeZone x, DateTimeZone y) => x.CompareTo(y) == 0;

        protected bool Equals(DateTimeZone other)
        {
            return CompareTo(other) == 0;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public override bool Equals(object? obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) 
                return false;

            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) 
                return true;

            if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) 
                return false;

            return Equals((DateTimeZone)obj);
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return HashCode.Combine(_dateTime, TimeZoneId);
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{nameof(DateTime)}: {_dateTime}, {nameof(TimeZoneId)}: {TimeZoneId}";
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: IMHO, you're much better off keeping them as separate fields than combining them into a custom struct.  Though if you do want to go that way, then consider using [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/) instead.  It already has a very good `ZonedDateTime` struct.  (I think you'll still need two separate fields for EF either way though.)

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint your suggestion is good enough for me. I'll store it as a DateTime & string. thanks